# How to quickly search an array of objects in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, search

Is there a way in Objective-C to search an array of objects by the contained object's properties, if the properties are of type string?

For instance, I have an `NSArray` of `Person` objects. `Person` has two properties, `NSString *firstName` and `NSString *lastName`.

What's the best way to search through the array to find everyone who matches 'Ken' anywhere in the `firstName OR lastName` properties?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Short answer: [NSArray:filteredArrayUsingPredicate:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/filteredArrayUsingPredicate:)

Long answer: [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 29):

try something like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName==%@ OR lastName==%@",@"Ken",@"Ken"];
NSArray *results = [allPersons filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use **NSPredicate** to filter your search from actual result array:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.property_name contains[c] %@",stringToSearch];
filteredPendingList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[mainArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"property_name"
                                                 ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [filteredPendingList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

So you will be getting the sorted array with filtered result. **property_name** above is the name of variable inside your object on which you want to perform your search operation. Hope it will help you.

Comment: his filteredArrayUsingPredicate method is relatively slow.

See here for speedier options:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21158730/42100

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do a linear search, comparing each entry in the array to see if it matches what you're looking for.

Comment: Does everyone who downvoted this think that NSPredicate does something other than a linear search?

Comment: It's not a detailed answer and doesn't provide sample code, but it's not wrong.  Using NSPredicate to create an entirely new array with filtered results is one way to do this, but a simple `for loop` over the array contents checking for what you want is just as good.