# Which has faster performance indexesOfObjectsPassingTest or filteredArrayUsingPredicate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, filtering, performance-testing

When needing to filter an NSArray to get a subset of the items in the array returned, which method is quicker more frequently and in edge cases?

Comment: First: profile (using Instruments) will tell you the difference. But honestly, if the performance is crucial to your app in this case, you are likely using the wrong approach. Objective-C by itself, NSPredicates, NSString comparisons, and many more idiomatic Objective-C implementations aren't really "fast" (iff you need that).

Comment: Even if we measure for you (or you measure for yourself), the answer to your question is going to depend on what you plan on doing with the results.  e.g. looping over the contents of an `NSIndexSet` returned by `-indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` calling `-objectAtIndex:` each time might not be the most efficient thing to do.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The following tests (compiled in Release mode, executed on a Mac Pro) *indicate* that
`filteredArrayUsingPredicate` is slower than `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest` if you use
a "textual" predicate, but faster if you use block-based predicate.
The fasted method in my test was a simple (fast-enumeration) loop that adds all matching
objects to a mutable array.

Results for filtering an array of 10,000,000 dictionaries, where about 50% match the predicate:

```
8.514334 (predicateWithFormat)
4.422550 (predicateWithBlock)
5.170086 (indexesOfObjectsPassingTest)
3.154015 (fast-enumeration + mutable array)
```

Of course the results may be different for other predicates.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSUInteger filter1(NSArray *a)
{
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"num > 1000 AND foo == 'bar'"];
    NSArray *filtered = [a filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
    return [filtered count];
}

NSUInteger filter2(NSArray *a)
{
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSDictionary *obj, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        return ([obj[@"num"] intValue] > 1000 && [obj[@"foo"] isEqualToString:@"bar"]);
    }];
    NSArray *filtered = [a filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
    return [filtered count];
}

NSUInteger filter3(NSArray *a)
{
    NSIndexSet *matching = [a indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSDictionary *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return ([obj[@"num"] intValue] > 1000 && [obj[@"foo"] isEqualToString:@"bar"]);
    }];
    NSArray *filtered = [a objectsAtIndexes:matching];
    return [filtered count];
}

NSUInteger filter4(NSArray *a)
{
    NSMutableArray *filtered = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSDictionary *obj in a) {
        if ([obj[@"num"] intValue] > 1000 && [obj[@"foo"] isEqualToString:@"bar"]) {
            [filtered addObject:obj];
        }
    }
    return [filtered count];
}

void testmethod(NSArray *a, NSUInteger(*method)(NSArray *a))
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSDate *t1 = [NSDate date];
        NSUInteger count = method(a);
        NSDate *t2 = [NSDate date];
        NSLog(@"%f", [t2 timeIntervalSinceDate:t1]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            [a addObject:@{@"num": @(arc4random_uniform(2000)), @"foo":@"bar"}];
        }
        testmethod(a, filter1);
        testmethod(a, filter2);
        testmethod(a, filter3);
        testmethod(a, filter4);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could try indexesOfObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent passingTest: which should be faster by using multiple processors.

Comment: @gnasher729: Good suggestion. I have done that, and interestingly, `indexesOfObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent` is (on my Intel Core i5 iMac with 4 cores) about *30% slower* than the non-concurrent version. Instruments shows that all worker threads spend a lot of time  in `OSSpinLockSlow` (which is necessary to protect access to the result index set).

Comment: I tested this with `indexesOfObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent` and in my case it was even slightly faster than the test with the fast enumeration. Since the resulting indices are already sorted even if you use the concurrent version this should be used as the  filtering method of choice. ~ Tested with Xcode 6.2 beta 3 (6C101) and [this MacBook Pro](https://github.com/Blackjacx/CurrentHardware/blob/master/MacBook%20Pro.png)

Comment: @blackjacx: Strange. I have tested the code again, and replacing `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` by `indexesOfObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent passingTest:` in my `filter3()` function makes it much slower.

Comment: Hmm yes this is really strange. You can test with my code. It is here on [Github](https://github.com/Blackjacx/FilterAlgorithmPerformanceTests).

Answer (score 9):

I tested this problem with the brand new Xcode 6 performance tests (Objective-C) with the test cases below. I got the following results indicating that the enumerationBlock with the flag `NSEnumerationConcurrent` is the fastest filtering method for large arrays:

```
testPerformancePredicateWithFormat - measured [Time, seconds] average: 0.189
testPerformancePredicateWithBlock - measured [Time, seconds] average: 0.093
testPerformanceEnumerationBlock - measured [Time, seconds] average: 0.092
testPerformanceIndexesOfObjectsPassingTest - measured [Time, seconds] average: 0.082
testPerformanceFastEnumeration - measured [Time, seconds] average: 0.068
testPerformanceEnumerationConcurrent - measured [Time, seconds] average: 0.036
```

Here the tests:

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>

@interface TestPMTests : XCTestCase
@property(nonatomic, copy)NSArray *largeListOfDictionaries;
@end

@implementation TestPMTests

- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];

    self.largeListOfDictionaries = [NSMutableArray array];

    // Initialize a large array with ~ 300.000 entries as Dictionaries of at least one key value pair {"id":"<any id>"}
}

- (void)testPerformancePredicateWithFormat {
    NSString *ID = @"204440e5-4069-48e8-a405-88882a5ba27e";
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.id == %@", ID];

    [self measureBlock:^{
        NSArray *filtered = [self.largeListOfDictionaries filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
        NSLog(@"Count: %d", filtered.count);
    }];
}

- (void)testPerformancePredicateWithBlock {
    NSString *ID = @"204440e5-4069-48e8-a405-88882a5ba27e";
    NSString *kID = @"id";
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSDictionary *d, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        return [d[kID] isEqualToString:ID];
    }];

    [self measureBlock:^{
        NSArray *filtered = [self.largeListOfDictionaries filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
        NSLog(@"Count: %d", filtered.count);
    }];
}

- (void)testPerformanceIndexesOfObjectsPassingTest {
    NSString *ID = @"204440e5-4069-48e8-a405-88882a5ba27e";
    NSString *kID = @"id";

    [self measureBlock:^{
        NSIndexSet *matchingIndexes = [self.largeListOfDictionaries indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSDictionary *d, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            return [d[kID] isEqualToString:ID];
        }];
        NSArray *filtered = [self.largeListOfDictionaries objectsAtIndexes:matchingIndexes];
        NSLog(@"Count: %d", filtered.count);
    }];
}

- (void)testPerformanceFastEnumeration {
    NSString *ID = @"204440e5-4069-48e8-a405-88882a5ba27e";
    NSString *kID = @"id";

    [self measureBlock:^{
        NSMutableArray *filtered = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSDictionary *d in self.largeListOfDictionaries) {
            if ([d[kID] isEqualToString:ID]) {
                [filtered addObject:d];
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"Count: %d", filtered.count);
    }];
}

- (void)testPerformanceEnumerationBlock {
    NSString *ID = @"204440e5-4069-48e8-a405-88882a5ba27e";
    NSString *kID = @"id";

    [self measureBlock:^{
        NSMutableArray *filtered = [NSMutableArray array];
        [self.largeListOfDictionaries enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *d, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            if ([d[kID] isEqualToString:ID]) {
                [filtered addObject:d];
            }
        }];
        NSLog(@"Count: %d", filtered.count);
    }];
}

- (void)testPerformanceEnumerationConcurrent {
    NSString *ID = @"204440e5-4069-48e8-a405-88882a5ba27e";
    NSString *kID = @"id";

    [self measureBlock:^{
        NSMutableArray *filtered = [NSMutableArray array];
        [self.largeListOfDictionaries enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent usingBlock:^(NSDictionary *d, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            if ([d[kID] isEqualToString:ID]) {
                [filtered addObject:d];
            }
        }];
        NSLog(@"Count: %d", filtered.count);
    }];
}
```

#### UPDATE

I changed the following in `-testPerformanceEnumerationConcurrent`:

```
dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
    [filtered addObject:d];
});
```

And the results are still better for the concurrent version that in all other tests.

```
-[TestPMTests testPerformancePredicateWithFormat average: 0.134
-[TestPMTests testPerformancePredicateWithBlock] average: 0.079
-[TestPMTests testPerformanceEnumerationBlock] average: 0.079
-[TestPMTests testPerformanceIndexesOfObjectsPassingTest] average: 0.068
-[TestPMTests testPerformanceFastEnumeration] average: 0.054
-[TestPMTests testPerformanceEnumerationConcurrent] average: 0.029
```

Comment: Note that `NSMutableArray` is *not thread-safe*. So adding objects from multiple threads as in your `testPerformanceEnumerationConcurrent` method can cause wrong results or crashes. You would have to use some locking to protect the mutable array against simultaneous access from different threads, and that makes things slow again. Compare my above comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157109/which-is-has-faster-performance-indexesofobjectspassingtest-or-filteredarrayusin/21158730#comment35118685_21158730.

Comment: Just looked this up myself and found your comment Martin.  Great point.

Comment: the `testPerformanceEnumerationConcurrent` does make my app crash cause of non thread-safe, if i use lock and unlock then the performance is same as the `testPerformancePredicateWithFormat `, i have best performance with the `testPerformanceFastEnumeration `