# Getting a values from array

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsarray

I have searchBar in my app,

What i want to do is when user types any character in searchBar, I want to get all the values starting with same character from my array.

Here is my code snippet i have tried but it crashes..

```
for (int i=0; i<[arr count]; i++) {
    for(NSString *name in [[arr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Merchant_Name"])
    {

        NSRange r = [name rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if(r.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            if(r.location== 0)//that is we are checking only the start of the naames.
            {
                [arr addObject:name];

            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Shows ERROR:-[__NSDictionaryM rangeOfString:options:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

Where i am making mistake?

**Please help and thanks in advance.**

**EDIT:**

```
arr =   {
        "Merchant_Id" = 1036;
        "Merchant_Name" = "Arzoo Hotels";
        "Merchant_Url" = "arzoo-hotels";
    },
        {
        "Merchant_Id" = 1037;
        "Merchant_Name" = "Ashika Mall";
        "Merchant_Url" = "ashika-mall";
    },
        {
        "Merchant_Id" = 1038;
        "Merchant_Name" = "At My Doorsteps";
        "Merchant_Url" = "at-my-doorsteps";
    },
        {
        "Merchant_Id" = 1039;
        "Merchant_Name" = "AVA Host";
        "Merchant_Url" = "ava-host";
    },
```

Comment: What is the crash? Also, this is not all the code - what is 'counter', what is Array?

Comment: We need crash details. But you might want to look at using a predicate instead of a loop.

Comment: does all the elements in `arr` is `NSString`, seems like element in `arr` are `NSDictionary`.

Comment: That error means that arr contains NSDictionaries and not NSStrings.

Comment: My arr contains value in this format `{
        "Merchant_Id" = 1012;
        "Merchant_Name" = AajKiItem;
        "Merchant_Url" = aajkiitem;
    },
        {
        "Merchant_Id" = 1013;
        "Merchant_Name" = Aaneri;
        "Merchant_Url" = aaneri;
    },
        {
        "Merchant_Id" = 1015;
        "Merchant_Name" = Adexmart;
        "Merchant_Url" = adexmart;
    }, ...` I want to compare on `Merchant_Name` how should i compare ?

Comment: This error doesn't match your reputation lavel.,

Answer (score 1):

For that, you should filter your array using NSPredicate.

Edit: Using predicate and filtering is much more readable and understandable. As stated in the comment, it might be slower, but you probably won't have 10,000,000+ strings you'd like to filter through, so saving 0.00001 second probably isn't worth writing a code 10 lines longer.

[Documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-SW3).

And here's a [whole tutorial about search bar and filtering data](http://www.appcoda.com/tag/search-display-controller/).

A quick example to filter an array and get values that begin with 'a' or 'c':

```
NSMutableArray *array =
    [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Nick", @"Ben", @"Adam", @"Melissa", nil];

NSPredicate *bPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] 'a'"];
NSArray *beginWithB = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:bPredicate];
// beginWithB contains { @"Adam" }.

NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] 'e'"];
[array filterUsingPredicate:sPredicate];
```

Comment: *"NSPredicate … It's much faster and much more optimised then what you could write."* - Do you have any reference confirming your statement? In my experience, `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` is **slower** than an explicit loop, compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/21158730/1187415.

Comment: It crashes here `NSArray *beginWithB = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:bPredicate];` shows `Can't do a substring operation with something that isn't a string (lhs = {
    "Merchant_Id" = 1007;
    "Merchant_Name" = 24HoursLoot;
    "Merchant_Url" = 24hoursloot;
} rhs = a)`

Answer (score 1):

Using Below code you can do straight search

```
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Merchant_Name LIKE[cd] '%@' ",searchText];
  NSArray *filter = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Using Below code you can do custom search

```
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Merchant_Name  beginswith[c] 'a'"];
  NSArray *aNames = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]
```

-use this code
  -And Set Delegate to Uitextfield.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSString *changedText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF['Merchant_Name'] contains %@",changedText];
    NSArray *filter = [arraydata filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    NSLog(@"%@%",changedText);

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Tried your answer and shows crash here `NSArray *filter = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];`and my log shows this `Can't do a substring operation with something that isn't a string (lhs = {
    "Merchant_Id" = 1007;
    "Merchant_Name" = 24HoursLoot;
    "Merchant_Url" = 24hoursloot;
} rhs = a)`

Comment: Or i tried your first answer i am not getting value of `searchText` log shows : `Merchant_Name LIKE[cd] "%@"` and my array filter is null

Comment: do me a faviour send your arr result to me.

Comment: See my **EDIT** in the question i want only `Merchant_Name`

Answer (score 0):

There is `NSMutableDictionary` type object in `arr`, try this to avoid crash:

```
 for(NSString *name in arr){
    if(![name isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
        continue;
    }

    NSRange r = [name rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if(r.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        if(r.location== 0)//that is we are checking only the start of the naames.
        {
            [Array addObject:name];
        }
    }
    counter++;
}
```