# Is it possible to delete dictionary from mutablearray while iterating?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

```
for (int i = 0; i< [optionDataArr count]; i++) {
    NSString *sName  = [[optionDataArr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:kOptionName];
    NSString *sPrice = [[optionDataArr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:kOptionExtraPrice];

    if (sName.length == 0  && sPrice.length == 0) {
          [optionDataArr removeObjectAtIndex:i];
    }  
}
```

Suppose `optionDataArr` contains a dictionary having no values and when above code executes i receive:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove items when using a plain old for loop, you cannot when using fast enumeration.

Your code is buggy, though. When you delete the nth element, the next element will be (n+2)th. You need to manually decrement the index by one to account for the shifted elements.

Also keep in mind, that in this case you really need to do "real time" bounds checking of the array length in the loop, and not just use a temporary variable holding the length (or you need to decrement that one as well).

Comment: Exactly. Just replace your code with: http://pastie.org/9461426

Comment: thnku@Eiko  @Szu for ur kind concern

Comment: @Szu it still giving same error  index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: @SKT Did you show your actual code, or did you "strip it down"?

Comment: @Eiko problem is once the dictionary gets deleted next time whenever optionDataArr is encountered it getting same error .

Comment: Well, then your next error is probably somewhere else. Track down where it crashes and post that code. Maybe in another question.

Answer (score 3):

Below this line:

```
[optionDataArr removeObjectAtIndex:i];
```

add this line:

```
i--;
```

So, the code would be:

```
if (sName.length == 0  && sPrice.length == 0) {
    [optionDataArr removeObjectAtIndex:i];
    i--;
}
```

Reason: When you remove an item from an array while you are iterating on it, the indexes get changed. So, that's why you would need to manually decrement index.

Answer (score 3):

Eiko answer is correct, but i wanted to show an other version using fast enumeration. You cannot remove items using fast enumeration, so you have do store the indexes and then remove the corresponding items later :

```
NSMutableIndexSet * indexesToRemove = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];

[optionDataArr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *dico, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([dico count] == 0)
        [indexesToRemove addIndex:idx];
}];

[optionDataArr removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexesToRemove];
```

**EDIT :**

As  Martin R sugested, you can also use `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest`method :

```
NSIndexSet * indexesToRemove = [optionDataArr indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSDictionary *dico, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return ([dico count] == 0);
}];
[optionDataArr removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexesToRemove];
```

Comment: This could be further simplified using `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:...`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157109/which-is-has-faster-performance-indexesofobjectspassingtest-or-filteredarrayusin indicated me that fast enumeration + mutableArray is faster than indexesOfObjectsPassingTest. NSMutableIndexSet is pretty close to an NSMutableArray (even if it doesn't inherit from it), so my guess is that enumerating is faster. Anyway, further test are needed depending of the case. Thanks for your suggestion, I edited my answer to add it.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use a standard for loop for this, provided you make the modifications that Eiko has already mentioned.

However, the idomatic way to handle this in Objective C is to iterate over a copy of the array:

```
for (id obj in [optionDataArr copy]) {
    // some processing code

    if (condition) {
        [optionDataArr removeObject:obj]
    }
}
```

While this does require a copy of the array, unless you know for sure that you are dealing with a significant amount of data, I would start with the readable version and optimise to the plain for loop when and if necessary.

Comment: I love lazy code, but this is not "idiomatic" here. In fact, it's rather fighting the language.
 The idiomatic way is something like 'NSIndexSet *removals = [optionDataArr indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:...]; [optionDataArr removeObjectsAtIndexes:removals];'

Comment: @Eiko - I completely agree with you for this simple case.  In practice, though, I tend to find that I need to do some additional processing on removed objects (eg, logging).  That's not as easy if you just have the indices.

Comment: ya it may works but i think its exhuastive way if we have large data @Sapi anyways Thnx for ur concern