# When iterating an NSMutableArray, how to delete one object then insert multiple objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, nsmutablearray

For example, if we have an instance of NSMutableArray, with 10 objects in it. When iterating over it, we found that we have to delete object a[2] and a[8], and then insert 3 objects at a[2] and 4 objects at a[8] continuously, how to do that at lowest time cost?

Any idea will be thankful!

Comment: Do you use Swift or Objective-C ? Just to know how to answer ;)

Comment: I'm using objc, thanks

Comment: Ok, So i this case you should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238436/is-it-possible-to-delete-dictionary-from-mutablearray-while-iterating/25238661#25238661 , which is almost all you need :)

Comment: Well, not exactly what I need, but your answer offered me a clue, I guess I have something in mind, I'm gonna test it in code later. Thanks

Comment: The deletion part is handled in the link i provided you. How do you determine which objects and how many must be inserted at the deleted indexes ?

Comment: I'm thinking about alloc init another mutable array, then iterate the original array and add each objects into the new array. When I find an object to replace, generate new objects and add them to the new array. After iteration, the new array is the result.

Comment: Actually, if the original array is a linked list, then things will be so easy : )

Comment: Sadly linked list aren't that used in practical use. I've added an answer according to your more detailed comments, maybe it will help you further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit :**  As @trojanfoe pointed out, it's nice to add that you should never edit an array while iterating it. This is true for many collection classes in many different languages; not just `NSMutableArray` & Objective-C. Doing so can easily leads to out-of-bounds index.

---

For your question, let's do it in two iteration. 
First, we want to save the indexes we want to delete, so we will iterate on the sourceArray.

```
NSMutableArray * indexesToRemove = [NSMutableArray array];

[sourceArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber * obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    if (obj.integerValue%2 == 1) {
        // Insert at first position
        [indexesToRemove insertObject:@(idx) atIndex:0];
    }
}];
```

It's important to save the index in an array and not a set, since you want to insert objects later. Also, add the new items at the beginning of the array is important, so you will iterate from the biggest index to the smallest, and will not have to shift the indexes according to the previously added items.

Now, you can, in a new iteration (this time on the index array), delete the items and add the new ones according to the indexes you saved :

```
[indexesToRemove enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber * obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

    NSUInteger indexToRemove = obj.unsignedIntegerValue;

    // Delete the item from the source array
    [sourceArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexToRemove];

    // Create the items you want to insert, do whatever you want in this method :]
    NSArray * itemsToAdd = [self generateElementsToAddAtIndex:indexToRemove];

    // Create the indexSet according to the start index and the number of objects you want to insert
    NSIndexSet * indexSet = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(indexToRemove, itemsToAdd.count)];

    // Insert the objects
    [sourceArray insertObjects:itemsToAdd atIndexes:indexSet];        
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

`[myMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:2 withObject:"5"];`
will it work ?

Comment: this will only replace it, ie 1 object for 1. OP is asking for multiple objects for 1, i guess

Comment: Yes, I'm asking for replacing one object with multiple objects

Answer (score 0):

First you have to delete object then use below line of code to insert multiple objects:

```
NSMutableOrderedSet *orderedSet = [[NSMutableOrderedSet alloc] init];
[orderedSet insertObjects:@[@"Eezy", @"Tutorials"] atIndexes:
                       [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)]];
NSLog(@"Result: %@", orderedSet);
```

Refer below reference link:

http://ios.eezytutorials.com/nsmutableorderedset-by-example.php#.VwIJIhN95fg

Answer (score 0):

For such a small array and so many operations, I consider replacing the array with a new one a good option - for performance as well as clarity.

Comment: I didn't down vote but I upvoted your answer to offset that downvote, because I think your opinion is  valuable : )