# isSubsetOfSet in NSPredicate string

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, nsset

I have difficulties checking if a nsorderedset is a subset of another nsorderedset in a NSPredicate string.

I can achieve the result with the block below:

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id object, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    NSOrderedSet *biggerSet = [object valueForKey:@"attributeName"];
    return [smallerSet isSubsetOfOrderedSet:biggerSet];
}];
```

but I believe that in string format could be more performant (am I wrong?).

tried things like @"attribute CONTAINS %@" and @"%@ IN attribute" but with no luck.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
NS(Ordered)Set *smallerSet = …
request.predicate =
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(attribute, $a, $a IN %@).@count == %lu",
         smallerSet, (unsigned long)[smallerSet count]];
```

The predicate checks if the number of "attribute" values contained in `smallerSet` is
equal to the number of elements in `smallerSet`. If yes, then `smallerSet` must be
a subset of the "attribute" set.

A string based predicate is not generally faster than a block based (compare
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21158730/1187415). But a Core Data fetch request (with a
SQlite store file) *cannot* use block based predicates.

Comment: on SQL data store I get 'Can't have a non-relationship collection element in a subquery'. I fear that there is something wrong with my custom object which is in the collection. But it overrides 'isEqual' and 'hash'. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like the custom object has to subclass NSManagedObject and probably be connected through a relationship.