# Swift NSPredicate filtering using set operations

Tags: swift, nspredicate

I'm trying to filter such that criteria is met for each AND every item in a set vice each OR every item.

If I use `groceryItem IN %@, desiredGroceries`, it acts like an OR statement.

Example:  I'm trying to return all grocery lists of `groceryItems` that included milk AND eggs (`desiredGroceries=Set("Milk", "Eggs")`).
If I use the above code, it returns all lists that included milk as well as lists that included eggs.
But I only want the lists that include BOTH milk and eggs.

What's the correct Predicate for this?

UPDATE:
From the Willeke's comments, I tried using .@count==%lu
This works if each groceryList only has one item.  However, if it has multiple items, I see inconsistent results when showing groceryLists.  Sometimes the filter works, other times it reports nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [isSubsetOfSet in NSPredicate string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25910695/issubsetofset-in-nspredicate-string)

Comment: Thanks.  The results still aren't as expected.  Maybe there's something wrong with my syntax: ```IN %@).count==%lu, sysFilter, [sysFilter.count])

Comment: I'm still learning subQuery, but doesn't .count refer to the number of items returned?

Comment: `[smallerSet count]` in Objective-c translates to `smallerSet.count` in Swift (and Objective-C). `.@count` is part of the predicate format, don't remove this `@`. See [NSExpression.init(forSubquery …](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsexpression/1411651-init).

Comment: It will be something like `"SUBQUERY(groceryItems, $groceryItem, $groceryItem IN %@).@count == %lu", desiredGroceries, desiredGroceries.count`