# Efficient means to enumerate an array looking for items in another array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

Without unintentionally killing performance, does this appear at first glance to be acceptable for perhaps 200 guid strings in one list compared for equality with 100 guid strings from another list to find the matching indexes.

I have a method signature defined like so...

```
-(NSArray*)getItemsWithGuids:(NSArray*)guids
```

And I wanted to take that passed in array of `guids` and use it in conjunction with this array...

```
NSArray *allPossibleItems; // Has objects with a property named guid.
```

... to obtain the indexes of the items in `allPossibleItems` which have the matching guids from `guids`

My first instinct was to try `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest` but after putting together the block, I wondered whether the iOS framework already offers something for doing this type of compare more efficiently.

```
-(NSArray*)getItemsWithGuids:(NSArray*)guids
    {
        NSIndexSet *guidIndexes = [allPossibleItems indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop)
    {
        SomeObjWithGuidProperty *someObject = obj;

        for (NSString *guid in guids) {
            if ([someObject.guid isEqualToString:guid]) {
                return YES;
            }
        }
        return NO;
    }];


    if (guidIndexes) {
        // Have more fun here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't set `*stop` to `YES` in your `if` statement. Doing that will mean `guidIndexes` will only ever contain at most 1 index.

Comment: Why is the return type of your `getItemsWithGuids:forGuids:` method set to be `NSArray *` but you return an `NSIndexSet`?

Comment: Check this thread, comparing different ways. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157109/which-has-faster-performance-indexesofobjectspassingtest-or-filteredarrayusingpr

Comment: @rmaddy  Sorry if that was confusing.  I'm going to return an array of the matching objects I find in `allPossibleItems` array using the `guidIndexes` found in the search.

Comment: "guid" sounds to me like a thing that would make a nice NSDictionary key.  Maybe a better design even beyond the scope of this question would be to keep your objects-with-guid properties in an indexed data structure, like NSDictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thought would be to use a set -

```
-(NSArray*)getItemsWithGuids:(NSArray*)guids inAllObjects:(NSArray *)allObjects 
{

   NSSet *matchGuids=[NSSet setWithArray:guids];
   NSMutableArray *matchingObjects=[NSMutableArray new];
   for (SOmeObjectWithGuidProperty *someObject in allObjects) {
       if ([matchGuids contains:someObject.guid]) {
           [matchingObjects addObject:someObject];
       }
   }

   return [matchingObjects copy];
}
```

Comment: `allGuids` should be: `NSSet *allGuids = [NSSet setWithArray:guids];`. And the `for` loop should be over `allObjects`.

Comment: Why do you say that?  I changed the function signature since in the original question, `allPossibleItems` comes from nowhere and although the input parameter is called `guids` it actually seems to contain instances of `SomeObjWithGuidProperty`

Comment: In the OP's code, `guids` is an array of `NSString` and `allObjects` is an array of `SomeObjWithGuidProperty`.

Comment: Answer is actually wrong. `[allObjects valueForKey:@"guid"]` will return `NSArray`, not `NSSet`. Moreover, there is no `someObject` declaration.

Comment: Thanks,  that was a typo between my brain and the keyboard.

Comment: Still problem with `someObject` :( I've checked initial version of your answer, but it also have problem - you used `SomeObjWithGuidProperty *someObject in guids`, but `guids` contains `NSString`s, not `SomeObjWithGuidProperty `s.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're working with Objective-C (not Swift) check out [YoloKit](http://mxcl.github.io/YOLOKit/).  In your case, you can do something like:

```
guids.find(^(NSString *guid){
    return [someObject.guid isEqualToString:guid];
});
```

Comment: A part of me wants to downvote my own post haha.  I think my suggestion only reduces the number of lines.  It doesn't make the algorithm more efficient.

Comment: A part of me wants to up-vote because I think this OP should choose brevity over efficiency for 100-element sized collections.  The reason I'm resisting the up-vote instinct is the reliance on net code which I distrust by default.  Ehhh +1 anyway, because skimming yolo reminds me of underscorejs, which is a godsend.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like it would have O(n^2) performance, which is bad. I think the solution of converting guids to an `NSSet` and then using `NSSet`'s `containsObject` would likely be much more performant. You could rewrite your `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest` code to use an `NSSet` and `containsObject` pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

If order doesn't matter much, I would suggest to change data structure here. Instead of using `NSArray`, consider to use `NSDictionary` with `guid` as key and `someObject` as value. In this case, you should use `-[NSDictionary objectsForKeys:notFoundMarker:]` method to obtain objects.

It will work much faster, than enumeration trough 2 arrays. If the `NSDictionary` key have a good hash function, accessing an element, setting an element, and removing an element all take constant time. `NSString` has good hash.

```
-(NSArray*)getItemsWithGuids:(NSArray*)guids {
    NSArray *objectsAndNulls = [allPossibleItemsDictionary objectsForKeys:guids notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]];
    if (objectsAndNulls) {
        // Have more fun here.
        // You should check that object in objectsAndNulls is not NSNull before using it
    }
    return objectsAndNulls;
}
```

**UPD** Unfortunately, there is no way to pass `nil` as notFoundMarker. If you can't provide usable notFoundMarker value and don't want to perform additional checks, you can query objects one by one and fill `NSMutableArray`. In this case you will avoid pass trough array to remove `NSNull`s:

```
-(NSArray*)getItemsWithGuids:(NSArray*)guids {
    NSMutableArray *objects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:guids.count];
    for (NSString *guid in guids) {
        SomeObjWithGuidProperty *object = allPossibleItemsDictionary[guid];
        if (nil != object) {
            [objects addObject:object];
        }
    }
    if (nil != objects) {
        // Have more fun here.
    }
    return object;
}
```